# Configure Macvim's text selection to not include character under cursor

Tags: vim, macvim

Using macvim, when I copy a text selection, it always includes the character under the cursor.

For example, if the cursor is at the far left and I press shift-down arrow, it selects the entire line **plus** the first character of the next line (since the cursor is sitting over the next line's first character).

Is there a way to configure macvim to not include the cursor character in text selections?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the `selection` option. By default it's set to `inclusive`, but you can change it to `exclusive` to make text selections act the way you want:

```
:set selection=exclusive
```

You can also set it to `exclusive` with the `behave` command:

```
:behave mswin
```

This also sets several other options, however, which may or may not be what you want. See the Vim help for the specifics.

```
:help :behave

:help 'selection'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that shift-down arrow activates visual character mode, and moves the cursor down a line. If you are trying to select entire lines, you would be better off using visual line mode, which is activated from normal mode by pressing `V` (shift-v). This will select the current line in its entirety. You can then extend your selection to include the lines above and below using the `k` (or up arrow) and `j` (or down arrow) keys.

When using Vim, I think it is better to go with the grain rather than to fight against it. Don't expect it to work the same way as other text editors. Accept that the Vim way is different.